# Get the count of each unique values included in an numerical array using numpy.unique

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given an numpy array `a`, I can use np.unique(a) to generate the unique values included in `a`. How can I get the count of each unique values included in `a`?

Comment: If you want the *count* of each unique element, you can use `from collections import Counter` then `print(Counter(a))`

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), it accepts a second argument called `return_counts`:

```
u, c = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
```

`c[i]` is the corresponding count for `u[i]`.